# (Python 3) Mapping objects to colors in an image according to their size

Tags: python-3.x, colors, jupyter-notebook, mapping, labeling

Say, after a some segmentation, you have the following image:

[image]

It doesn't look polished, I know, but after some morphological operations it will turn exactly into what I need it for.

My question is: is there any scikit-image / OpenCV / other library's method which would take this image as input, would calculate objects' size and return a mapped/labeled result as follows: All objects which are bigger than average size - colored in red, the rest - in blue?

I've used `scipy.ndimage.label()` to get total objects' amount and number of pixels per object, and then calculated the average object size in the array.